# Problem using rep() in R. Invalid "times" argument

Tags: r, dataframe, rep

I looked for a solution in the forum but I didn´t get any.

I´m working with a fish database and I´m trying to transform my data frame from this (MRE):

```
 df_initial <- structure(list(year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L), haul = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), species = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Merluccius merluccius", class = "factor"), 
    length = c(29L, 33L, 34L, 37L, 10L, 11L, 12L), number = c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

to this

```
  df_final <-structure(list(year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L), haul = c(11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Merluccius merluccius", class = "factor"), 
    length = c(29L, 29L, 33L, 34L, 37L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), number = c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Namely, I want to replicate the length size by its number and keeping all the columns.

I´ve tried several approaches using the function **rep()** but I always get the same error: *invalid 'times' argument* . I´ve also tried playing with the data type but with no success.

What am I doing wrong?.

Here it is the last code I ran

```
df_final <- df_initial[rep(row.names(df_initial), df_initial$number), 1:5]
```

Any help will be more than welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example code seems to work correctly - it might be worth checking that it causes the error reported on your computer

Comment: @Miff I don´t know why with my example the code works but with my whole database (>460,000 observations) it doesn´t.

Comment: That would happen if any of your numbers are `NA`. `any(is.na(df_initial$number))` would confirm if that's the problem

Comment: You and zephryl were right. I have several NAs in the number column as a result of calculation mistake in a previous step. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is most likely caused by `NA` values in `number`. You'll have to deal with these first, either by dropping them or, if you want to retain them in the output, replacing `NA` with some value. Here's how to do both, using either base R or {tidyr}.

#### Remove rows with `NA`s

**base R:**

```r
# add NA values to example
df_initial$number[5:6] <- NA_integer_

df_cleaned <- df_initial[!is.na(df_initial$number), ]
df_final <- df_cleaned[rep(row.names(df_cleaned), df_cleaned$number), 1:5]

df_final

#>     year haul               species length number
#> 1   2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     29      2
#> 1.1 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     29      2
#> 2   2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     33      1
#> 3   2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     34      1
#> 4   2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     37      1
#> 7   2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 7.1 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 7.2 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 7.3 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 7.4 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
```

**tidyr:**

```r
library(tidyr)

df_final <- df_initial %>% 
  drop_na(number) %>% 
  uncount(weights = number, .remove = FALSE)

df_final

#>    year haul               species length number
#> 1  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     29      2
#> 2  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     29      2
#> 3  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     33      1
#> 4  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     34      1
#> 5  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     37      1
#> 6  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 7  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 8  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 9  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 10 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
```

#### Replace `NA`s

**base R:**

```r
df_cleaned <- df_initial
df_cleaned$number[is.na(df_initial$number)] <- 1L
df_final <- df_cleaned[rep(row.names(df_cleaned), df_cleaned$number), 1:5]

df_final

#>     year haul               species length number
#> 1   2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     29      2
#> 1.1 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     29      2
#> 2   2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     33      1
#> 3   2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     34      1
#> 4   2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     37      1
#> 5   2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     10      1
#> 6   2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     11      1
#> 7   2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 7.1 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 7.2 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 7.3 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 7.4 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
```

**tidyr**

```r
df_final <- df_initial %>% 
  replace_na(list(number = 1L)) %>% 
  uncount(weights = number, .remove = FALSE)
df_final

#>    year haul               species length number
#> 1  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     29      2
#> 2  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     29      2
#> 3  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     33      1
#> 4  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     34      1
#> 5  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     37      1
#> 6  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     10      1
#> 7  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     11      1
#> 8  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 9  2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 10 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 11 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
#> 12 2011   11 Merluccius merluccius     12      5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>